# Fatal Exception: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1, retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: android, api, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, httpexception

After some freezes, I get this error message.

I am not able to identify the reason for this problem. When I do Debug it shows that my app stops at different times. Sometimes it does 6 loops. Sometimes less or more. And the number of a DISPATCHER WORKER is not always the same in my ERROR message.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found
        at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:53)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Code:

```
class HeroesListViewModel (private val dbRepository: DbRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val heroesData: LiveData<List<Hero>> = dbRepository.getAllHeroes()
    var resultHeroes = ArrayList<Base>()
    var heroes = ArrayList<Hero>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            heroes = getAllHeroDetails()
            dbRepository.addAllHeroes(heroes)
        }
    }

    suspend fun getHeroTitles(): Heroes {
        return dbRepository.getRemoteHeroes()
    }

    suspend fun getHero(uid:Int): Base {
        return dbRepository.getRemoteHero(uid)
    }

    suspend fun getPlanet(uid:Int): PlanetBase {
        return dbRepository.getRemotePlanet(uid)
    }

    suspend fun getFilms(): FilmsBase {
        return dbRepository.getRemoteFilms()
    }

    suspend fun getAllHeroDetails(): ArrayList<Hero> {
        val heroTitles = getHeroTitles()
        val films = getFilms()
        for (i in heroTitles.heroes.indices) {
            resultHeroes.add(getHero(heroTitles.heroes[i].uid.toInt()))
            heroes.add(resultHeroes[i].result.hero)
            heroes[i].uid = resultHeroes[i].result.uid.toInt()
            heroes[i].homeworld = getPlanet(
                resultHeroes[i].result.hero.homeworld?.last()
                    .toString()
                    .toInt()
            ).result.planetProperties.name
            heroes[i].films = ArrayList()
            for (j in films.filmsResult.indices) {
                if (heroes[i].url in films.filmsResult[j].filmsProperties.characters) {
                    heroes[i].films.add(films.filmsResult[j].filmsProperties.title)
                }
            }
        }
        return heroes
    }
}
```

Comment: It works if I insert a loop inside a coroutine and use async - await 
val job1 = async {getHero(heroTitles.heroes[i].uid.toInt()) }
resultHero.add(job1.await()) for my requests but anyway it crashes after some time with the same Error

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate your fields when debugging. It looks like one of your url is pointing to an invalid resource.

Comment: Hero(height=172, mass=77, hairColor=blond, skinColor=fair, eye_color=blue, birthYear=19BBY, gender=male, created=2021-12-20T08:49:35.192Z, edited=2021-12-20T08:49:35.192Z, name=Luke Skywalker, homeworld=Tatooine, url=https://www.swapi.tech/api/people/1, films=[A New Hope, The Empire Strikes Back, Return of the Jedi, Revenge of the Sith], favourites=false, uid=1)

Comment: - everything works fine.   My app creates objects from API as was expected. But after 4-7 objects it crashes. I suppose it is because of a too-long responsive time. Some thread problem but I don't have enough experience to find out by myself where it is=((( When I launch I see freezing of the App, then I get an error message((

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line `val heroTitles = getHeroTitles()` and see what the `heroTitles` has. You can post the response here. Maybe post the first 10 entries.